# Vue and defineProps using TypeScript type with never gives vite error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to get a component working with TypeScript, Nuxt and Vue

But Vue seems to have a different take on TypeScript than I'm used to.

I get this error:
`[plugin:vite:vue] [@vue/compiler-sfc] type argument passed to defineProps() must be a literal type, or a reference to an interface or literal type.`

This is my current code.

```js
<template>
    <component :is="component" :to="to" :href="href" @click="$emit('click')">
        <slot/>
    </component>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
interface ButtonButtonBase {
    type?: string
    size?: "sm" | "md" | "lg"
    disabled?: boolean
    loading?: boolean
}

interface ButtonExternalLink {
    href: string
    to?: never
}

interface ButtonInternalLink {
    href?: never
    to: string
}

type ButtonProps =
    | ButtonInternalLink
    | ButtonExternalLink
    | ButtonButtonBase

withDefaults(defineProps<ButtonProps>(), {
    type: "button",
    size: "md",
    disabled: false,
    loading: false
})
</script>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
    name: "CButton",
    computed: {
        component() {
            if (this.to || this.href) return resolveComponent("NuxtLink")
            return "button"
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is having a component that takes either of the types but should not be able to take both to and href as a property. I have a similar code in a React component that works flawless and now I want something similar in my Vue project but TypeScript seems.

I've goggled to try and find a solution but most is saying I would need to defineProps inside of the defineProps object, which I don't understand how I would get never to work then.

Also Vetur doesn't seem to understand that my props exist when the props is defined outside of defineComponent. So if that could be saved to without actually having it in the defineComponent that would be great as I want to not bloat the script tag.

Comment: Your problem is a known issue and is [marked as an enhancement](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4294#issuecomment-896082769)

Comment: The recommended extension for Vue 3 is Volar no longer Vetur which was great for Vue 2: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar
In my opinion it works way better with TypeScript